# PL\SQL in APEX: Long Column names

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have an *existing database (and its APEX Application)* with Table-column names longer than 30 chars. So I can't change the names of columns.
I have found out that it is impossible to refer to long columns or fields (with names longer than 30 chars) in PL\SQL from APEX forms.

My aim is to be able to calculate fields/Columns from other fields/Columns e.g by addition, subtraction etc..

Any ideas are welcome..

Comment: Create views with shorter column names and base the APEX pages on those?

Comment: Version of both database and APEX would help. I'm presuming database 12.2

Comment: thanks for your quick answers. The Versions are; APEX: 5.1, DB: Oracle 11g.

Comment: Oracle 11g **database** does not allow column names to exceed 30 chars, so you can't have that problem. You may have APEX items based on columns that have **item** names > 30 chars.  Just shorten them.